# How do I fix Linux Mint splash logo and Plymouth settings?

Tags: boot, 64-bit, linux-mint, nvidia-geforce, splash

I've recently upgraded a Linux Mint x64 from Petra (16) to Rafaela(17.2), using  `apt-get dist-upgrade`.  After finally resolving all `dpkg` errors, I rebooted.

At bootup, instead of showing the Linux Mint logo, it shows the flashing dots during boot `. . . .` and the colors look wrong; The dots are dark green on black.

There was a problem with the `/etc/fstab` the system should have shown the `S_kip or M_anual fix` dialog, but was invisible due to a video setting problem. Rebooting in recovery text mode showed the `fstab` error message and was fixed.

Googling shows it might have something to do with [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth). How would I go about to fixing the Plymouth config?

Specs:

- Linux Mint x64 17.2 Rafaela
- nVidia GeForce 210 ASUS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following procedure fixed the bootup graphics:

Edit the grub configuration:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

At this line position:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Add the following:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=auto
```

Update the GRUB with the new configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

[*Source*](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1570)